# Navigating to Salesforce Record

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to navigate to respective record's detail page for a recordid when 
I click on Google Maps marker from JavaScript, but it doesn't work. Am I missing anything?

Below is the code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location = 'https://na15.salesforce.com/'+addrInstances[i].id;
    console.log('------+addrInstances[0].Location__Latitude__s);
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry.. My question is somehow I couldnt go to respective record's detail page.. Am I missing anything..?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but for navigation you can just use `window.location='/'+id`.

For salesforce1 have a look (Mobile navigation).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm

Comment: Thanks.I am not doing on Salesforce1 or mobile..